# Fail to install tensorflow-gpu: could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorboard<1.11.0,>

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to install tensorflow 1.10 using pip on Ubuntu 16.04:
pip install -U --install-option="--prefix=my_path" https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-1.10.1-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl

But it reports:

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorboard<1.11.0,>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow-gpu==1.10.1) (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for tensorboard<1.11.0,>=1.10.0 (from tensorflow-gpu==1.10.1)